# How to populate an excel combo box with a database from sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, combobox

I want to populate a combo box in excel with values from a table in SQL server directly. Also keep in mind that I will need to use the combo box values to auto populate some other fields in the excel document (based on the selection from combo box). What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is a pretty broad question here.

Comment: I connected to an sql server and loaded data into a sheet in excel then referenced the values from the sheet into the combo box

Comment: OK. So why can't you load the data into the combobox instead? I have no idea what you have done and I can't see you screen. I don't even know what you are trying to do here.